# May we, please, have syntax highlighting enabled for CSEducators?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was drafting an answer to a question, and there was significant chunks of code. Some HTML and others CSS. I noticed that none of it was being highlighted as I was expecting. I even fleshed out an HTML snippet to make it a complete 'page' from `<!DOCTYPE>` to `</html>`, and still nothing.

Using the explicit controls from the Meta SE [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/351780), I tried again. Still nothing.

I experimented with the same code on SO and it all worked as intended.

Turns out that it has to be enabled individually for each site. That only happens when requested through meta. Therefore, as a long-term user of CSEducators, I'd like to ask for syntax highlighting to be enabled for our site.

Syntax highlighting would be helpful in larger chunks of code. Some examples currently on-site are:

- Multiple answers to [Interesting Programming Exercises to Teach Inheritance?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/4689/104)
- Is it bad to force my students not to return early? has [two](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4442/104) [answers](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4453/104) with large-ish code blocks
- What should be included in a best practices C course? also has [two](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4077/104) [answers](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4267/104) with chunks of code
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4679/104) to Once implicit/inferred typing is introduced, how can I impress upon students the importance of not abusing it?
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4535/104) to How Effective Is “Rosetta Code” as a Teaching Technique?
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4509/104) to A meaningful exercise that requires using a destructor
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4490/104) to My teacher said that java is pass-by-reference when the type is not a primitive
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/4353/104) to How to avoid misconceptions about while loop when using null loop
- [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4338/104) to Explaining to students why to use double instead of float (unless there's a very good reason)

Answer (score 1):

This simply needs to be done.  Other StackExchange areas have it.  What is the obstacle?

Comment: To my understanding, it is not automatic for any site. Rather the site must request it, with a sufficiently positive vote on a meta question. The mods then present the case to the "appropriate channels" and with the votes, and reasons, from the meta post, they then enable it. I do believe we've met the requirements, and just have to await the activation.